# Overflow auto/scroll doesn't work correctly in FF with huge innerhtml value

Tags: html, css, firefox

This works as expected on 30 rows but increases block height over 50% after inserting e.g. 100 rows into it. Can anyone explain what happens? I noticed this bug in FF only.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html style="height:100%;">
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body style="height:100%;background:grey;padding:0;margin:0;">
    <table style="height:100%;">
        <tr>
            <td style="height:100%;">
                <div style="background:white;height:50%; overflow: auto">
                    <script>
                        // try 100 to see a bug 
                        for (i = 0; i <= 30; i++) {
                            document.write(i + " Sample text<br>");
                        }
                    </script>
                </div>
                <div style="background:blue; height:50%">
                Sample text
                </div>  
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why are you using a table here? Wouldn't the result be exactly the same when omitting it?

Comment: the table looks completely useless in this case, have you tried what happens if you remove it? and what happens if you're setting overflow to 'scroll' manually?

Comment: @elusive it wouldn't. but I need to use table on my page. I just simplified

Comment: How about the height of `tbody` and `tr`, then? Those are not defined here. Percent-values are always a bit tricky.

Comment: @elusive setting tbody height to 100% solved the problem. thanks a lot! you may write an answer that I will accept if you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the record: Setting `tbody`'s height to 100% should solve that problem. Be careful when using percent-values, since they are really tricky sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

My tests show that adding tbody with height: 100%; will fix the issue.

Comment: elusive was first in 10 ten mitunes difference but thanks, bazmegakapa, for attention paid to my question btw.